# Can't log into mysql shell

Tags: mysql, logins

When I try to log into the mysql shell with:

```
mysql -u root
```

then I get:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

How do I log onto the mysql shell?

I have been googling this left and right and trying all those proposed solutions on stackoverflow and elsewhere but nothing seems to work.

I have tried adding `-p` at the end. Same error.

I have tried going by this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run
The first answer, I already have mysql-server installed.
The second answer doesn't work.
The third answer, i cannot implement step no. 3:

```
mysql -u root
```

and in the second step the process just hangs with message:

```
mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2017-09-26T16:30:40.563159Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2017-09-26T16:30:40.566955Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
```

So the question is, how do I log onto the mysql shell?

Comment: What does `ps -ef | grep mysqld` give you? Specifically, I'm looking for the value of the `--socket` parameter of the running mysqld process

Comment: mysql     1039     1  0 17:29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Answer (score 0):

Please, review my.cnf files (see oficial documentation for file locations https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html).

Search under the [client] section if exist an entry called *socket*, i.e:

```
[client]
port=3306
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Replace it with the right path to mysql.sock and try again.
To get the mysql.sock, use `ps -FU mysql -H | more` and get the `--socket` value

Comment: there was no socket entry in .my.cnf. I typed in the ps command you sent and got: mysql     1039     1  0 312739 154556 0 17:29 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/mysqld. So I added line: socket=/usr/sbin/mysqld under mysql in .my.cnf. I still cannot access mysql, its almost the same error: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/usr/sbin/mysqld' (13)

Comment: Could you tell us the Linux Distro/Version? i.e `cat /etc/centos-release` for CentOS 7.
MySQL|Maria|Percona version? i.e `yum info mysql-server` on CentOS/RHEL
Where did you find the _my.cnf_ that have not socket? 
If the file start with a dot "." (as you typed in the answer) please remove it renamming the file `mv .my.cnf my.cnf`
Could you give us the `ls -lh /var/run/` output please?
How did you install mysql?

Comment: Its a linux mint 17.3. fully upgraded with update upgrade. its an old .my.cnf file i've been using in other systems. the ls command gives a full screen of output that is difficult to display here, are you looking for anything specific? I was following this to install mysql: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04.

Comment: Maybe I should just uninstall mysql and install it again. If so, how would be best for me to go about doing that?

Comment: Ok, which MySQL version are you running?
Also, I need to know if the `/var/run/mysqld` directory exists and it content. 
If MySQL was intalled with apt-get, so the directory must exist.

Comment: mysql --version gives me: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper. /var/run/mysqld exists and it contains mysqld.pid  mysqld.sock  mysqld.sock.lock. I was using apt-get when installing mysql.

Comment: Perfect, now try to run this command and add here the output `my_print_defaults mysqld`